# Несколько вопросов по поводу событий в JS

Tags: javascript, frontend, javascript-events

Делаю панельку с соц. кнопками с помощью спрайтов, после верстки надо было сделать открытие ссылки при клике на иконку, так как сейчас учу js, решил попрактиковаться на нем.
Такой вот код не работает:

```css
body {
     background-color: lavender;
    }
    
    .icons_main_class {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    }
    
    .icons_main_class li{
    background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/sprites/share/packs/174834-social-media-logos.png);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-size: 13rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .icons_main_class li:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .social1 {
    background-position: 20% -0.3%;
    }
    
    .social2 {
    background-position: 40% 0;
    }
    
    .social3 {
    background-position: 99% 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ul class="icons_main_class">
      <li class="social1" id='check' onclick="document.getElementById('check').window.open('https://google.com');"></li>
      <li class="social2"></li>
      <li class="social3"></li>
     </ul>
</html>
```

Но если написать просто так, то все работает:

```
<ul class="icons_main_class">
    <li class="social1" onclick="window.open('https://google.com');"></li>
    <li class="social2"></li>
    <li class="social3"></li>
 </ul>
```

Собственно интересно, почему в данном случае не нужно получать доступ по id (и он тоже вообще не нужен) через GetElementByID? В каких случаях его нужно использовать (если обращаться не к текущему элементу)?

Если использовать

```
<ul class="icons_main_class">
    <li class="social1" id='check' onclick="document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = 'some text';"></li>
<li class="social2"></li>
    <li class="social3"></li>
 </ul>
```

то все также работает, разница в том что для innerHTML нужно знать что содержит элемент, чтобы в нем написать нечто или как?

И последний вопрос - есть ли разница между использованием `onclick="document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = 'some text';"` вместо `onclick="this.innerHTML = 'some text';"` ? Работают они одинаково, но не понимаю разницы между всем этим, что когда нужно/можно/лучше использовать...

Comment: во время редактирования поста нажмите ctrl+m, откроется песочница, потом нажмете вставить в сообщение

Comment: искать элементы по id нужно если требуется взаимодействие именно с этим элементом для отработки скрипта. про this лучше отдельно почитайте, в данном случае это элемент у которого обрабатываем click.  бтв скрипты лучше не писать в атрибуты, пишите в отдельном месте.

Comment: в вашем случае лучше использовать this для читаемости

Comment: yolosora, а какие то "функциональные" различия есть между ними?) должны быть наверное, может в даном примере работают одинаково, но хотелось бы узнать разницу в разиличных ситуацих...

Comment: это абсолютно разные вещи. `this` это грубо говоря текущий элемент, `getElementById` стоит понимать буквально, это метод который ищет и берет элемент по указанному id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Собственно интересно, почему в данном случае не нужно получать доступ по id (и он тоже вообще не нужен) через GetElementByID? В каких случаях его нужно использовать (если обращаться не к текущему элементу)?

Потому что здесь требуется доступ к глобальному объекту `window` (кстати, его [можно вообще не указывать](https://javascript.ru/window)), а не к свойствам элемента с `id="check"`.

Если не нужно обращаться собственно к элементу страницы, то и `getElementById()` использовать не нужно. Как и `this`.

Comment: понял, спасибо, сударь)

Comment: @chase, если вам помог ответ, вы можете принять его (нажав на галочку), а также проголосовать за (нажав стрелку вверх).